# phpunit mock does not count the function call

Tags: php, testing, mocking, phpunit

I have a unit test where I create a mock object:

```php
 $resetTokenManagerStub = $this->getMockBuilder(ObjectManager::class)->getMock();
```

I make this a return value of another mock object

```php
 $managerRegistryStub->method('getManagerForClass')->willReturn($resetTokenManagerStub);
```

I check if it was called exactly one time:

```php
 $resetTokenManagerStub->expects($this->once())->method('persist');
```

if I put a var_dump just before the call in the actual unit I see that I pass the code there and that the stub is the `resetTokenManagerStub`, but still the test result is:

```sh
There was 1 failure:

1) App\Tests\Service\UserServiceTest::testGeneratePasswordResetToken with data set #0 (Mock_User_a375caf8 Object (...), 'generatedToken')
Expectation failed for method name is equal to 'persist' when invoked 1 time(s).
Method was expected to be called 1 times, actually called 0 times.
```

Why doesn't it count the call? Is it because I used it as a return value of another mock? The object I get when I call `getManagerForClass()` is the same as the one in the unittest. I did a `ar_dump` on it and both look the same:

```php
object(Mock_ObjectManager_142d72a2)#26 (4) {
...

object(Mock_ObjectManager_142d72a2)#26 (4) {
...
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Once again I was stupid. sorry for this post. This is like the rubber ducky method. I struggle for an hour, and when I submit it to a forum I see what I was doing wrong...

The `$resetTokenManagerStub->expects($this->once())->method('persist');` line was being called after the actual function call...